# anonymous functions in typescript are not converted to javascript properly

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm writing my application using nodejs 5.10.1 with tsc 1.8.9

In general i'm converting the syntax of anonymous functions to typescript syntax. which means converting

```
function(){}
```

to

```
()=>{}
```

so I have several places where I changed to the typescript method of declaring anonymous functions:

```
 async.each(params.fjso, (filePath:string, callback:Function)=> {
```

is converted to:

```
async.each(params.fjso, (filePath, callback) => {
```

another example:

```
async.forEachOf(params.fjso, (filePath:string, fileIdx:number,callback:Function)=>{
```

is converted to:

```
async.forEachOf(params.fjso, (filePath, fileIdx, callback) => {
```

as you can see the code part `()=>{}` is not modified to `function(){}`.

I'm new to typescript so i'm probably missing something... but what?

tsc complication doesn't show any error messages.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're targeting ES6 where the arrow function syntax is natively supported so no conversion is required (as in node.js 4+).

Comment: i'm targeting es6. since i'm using node 5.10.1 it should work. i'll investigate it further thanks

Comment: If you want the older syntax modify tsconfig.json so that the target is es5 or less.  Otherwise you're good as-is.